# How can I use Java 8 streams to sort an ArrayList of objects by a primitive int member?

Tags: sorting, java-8, java-stream, primitive

Here is an example class.  I know the simplest thing would be to change the members from primitive type `int` to object `Integer` and use stream/lambda/sorted, but there may be reasons to only have a primitive type `int` such as space.
How could I use the streams API to sort a `List<DateRange>` by `int` member `startRange`?

```
List<DateRange> listToBeSorted = new ArrayList<DateRange>();


static private class DateRange
{
    private int startRange ;
    private int endRange ;
    public int getStartRange() {
        return startRange;
    }
    public void setStartRange(int startRange) {
        this.startRange = startRange;
    }
    public int getEndRange() {
        return endRange;
    }
    public void setEndRange(int endRange) {
        this.endRange = endRange;
    }
}
```

Comment: note compareTo will not work with primitive types.  It requires an Object

Comment: there is at least a 16 byte overhead to having two Integers instead of two primitive int members

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
List<DateRange> sortedList = listToBeSorted.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(DateRange::getStartRange))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked for a way to do it with streams, but if you are OK with sorting the original list in-place, you don't need streams for this. Just use the [`List.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method:

```
listToBeSorted.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(DateRange::getStartRange));
```

Comment: Much more efficient.

Comment: Both of these are helpful thanks.  In the case above I purposely made a copy of the List because I am iterating through the sorted list while modifying the original list.